# I am confused what datatype would name be? A function datatype or a boolean datatype since it would return a boolean?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, types, boolean

I am confused what datatype "name" is for this. Would name be a function datatype or would it be a boolean datatype? I am confused because name would return a boolean datatype so would that make "name" a boolean datatype?

```
var name = function(data){ 
    if (data>= 33)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `name` is a function that returns a boolean, as simple as that

Comment: Javascript is a "dynamically-typed" language. That means that variables such as `name` here do not have "intrinsic" types. Only *values* have types - but variables can be assigned values of any type. You can assign, say `var a = "hello world"` (a string), then shortly afterwards say `a = 0` (a number), then `a = false` (a boolean), and so on. This is totally different from "statically-typed" languages like eg. Java where you declarer a variable as specifically, say, a String, and the compiler will throw an error if you try to assign a Boolean value to it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name is a function

Whereas when you execute it, it returns a boolean.

Hence name() would be a boolean.

In other words: "name" is of type Function and its "return value" is of type boolean.

You can check this with typeof too.

```js
const name = function(data){ 
  if (data>= 33) return true;
  return false;
}

const execName = name(50);

console.log('name', typeof name);
console.log('execName', typeof execName);
```

Comment: Thank you, so "name" would be a function but its datatype is a boolean, correct?

Comment: More like: "name" is of type Function and its "return value" is of type boolean.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ever confused as to what data type something is, you can use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Usage:

```
console.log(typeof(name)); // returns "function"
```

If you want to know the type of data it returns:

```
console.log(typeof(name(34))); // returns "boolean"
```